# How can I descending sort a grouping based on the count of the reduction array in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

Importing this dataset as a table:

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Housing-Development/Registration-Contacts/feu5-w2e2#revert

I use the following query to perform an aggregation and then attempt to sort in descending order based on the reduction field. My intention is sort based on the count of that field or to have the aggregation create a second field called count and sort the grouping results in descending order of the reduction array count or length. How can this be done in rethinkdb?

query:

```
r.table("contacts").filter({"Type": "Agent","ContactDescription" : "CONDO"}).hasFields("CorporationName").group("CorporationName").ungroup().orderBy(r.desc('reduction'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you're going for, but does this do what you want?  If not, what do you want to be different in the output?

```
r.table("contacts")
 .filter({"Type": "Agent","ContactDescription" : "CONDO"})
 .hasFields("CorporationName")
 .group("CorporationName")
 .ungroup()
 .merge(function(row){ return {count: row('reduction').count()}; })
 .orderBy(r.desc('count'))
```

Comment: This query produces the desired result.

Comment: Is that possible I can sort on fields inside reduction?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

```
r.table("contacts").filter({"Type": "Agent","ContactDescription" : "CONDO"}).hasFields("CorporationName").group("CorporationName").count().ungroup().orderBy(r.desc('reduction'))
```

See that `.count()`? That is a map-reduce operation to get the count of each group.

I haven't tested the query on your dataset. Please comment in case you had problems with it.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to add a count field and preserve the original document, you need to use `map` and `reduce`. In your case, it should be something like:

```
r.table("contacts").filter({"Type": "Agent","ContactDescription" : "CONDO"})
    .hasFields("CorporationName")
    .group("CorporationName")
    .map(r.row.merge({count:1}))
    .reduce(function(left, right){
        return {
            count: left('count').add(right('count')),
            <YOUR_OTHER_FIELDS>: left('<YOUR_OTHER_FIELDS>'),
            ...
        };
    })
    .ungroup().orderBy(r.desc(r.row('reduction')('count')))
```

---

**EDIT:**

I am not sure if this can do the trick, but it is worth a try:

```
.reduce(function(left, right){
    return left.merge({count: left('count').add(right('count'))})
})
```

Comment: The query you created does order in descending order, but the reduction only displays the count and not the data in the grouping without the count. Can it be display that data while still sorting DESC according to count?

Ordered w/ count:
  {
        "group": "THE ANDREWS ORGANIZATION",
        "reduction": 167
    },
   
WITHOUT COUNT:

    {
        "group": "THE 231 16TH STREET CONDO",
        "reduction": [
            {
                "ContactDescription": "CONDO",
                "CorporationName": "THE 231 16TH STREET CONDO",
**TRUNCATED**

Comment: Right but then I need to specify all fields, is there a way to have it add a count field in addition to the complete aggregation done without the count?

Comment: @BarryG I am as well wondering if there is a way to do that. However, this is the best I can get. I further edited the answer, but since I currently do not have a rethinkdb at hand, I cannot test if this works. You may try and let me know :)